# Dockerize Angular Tour of Heroes

Tags: angular, docker, dockerfile

I´m new at docker and I´m trying to dockerize the angular sample project "Tour of heroes" which you can find here:

https://angular.io/generated/zips/toh-pt6/toh-pt6.zip

I have created the Dockerfile from what I have researched and it looks like this:

**DOCKERFILE**

```
FROM node:latest

RUN mkdir -p /src/app
WORKDIR /src/app

COPY package.json /src/app
RUN npm install

COPY ./ /src/app

EXPOSE 4200
ENTRYPOINT npm start
```

And when I build the container it doesn´t throw any error.

Then I try to run the image with

`docker run -p 4200:4200 toh:app`

Then  it run ng serve (Idk why, I didn´t put this command on the Dockerfile, but I think it´s due to the version of Node(?)) and says it compiled succesfully.

But on localhost:4200 appear a message of "Localhost didn´t send any data" with ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

I´m seeing that when it comes to Docker questions people usually post the package.json file too, so I post it too.

**PACKAGE.JSON**

```
{
    "name": "angular-tour-of-heroes",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "~10.1.6",
  "@angular/common": "~10.1.6",
  "@angular/compiler": "~10.1.6",
  "@angular/core": "~10.1.6",
  "@angular/forms": "~10.1.6",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.1.6",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.1.6",
  "@angular/router": "~10.1.6",
  "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.11.0",
  "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
  "tslib": "^2.0.0",
  "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1001.7",
  "@angular/cli": "~10.1.7",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.1.6",
  "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
  "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
  "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
  "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
  "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
  "karma": "~5.0.0",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
  "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
  "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
  "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
  "protractor": "~7.0.0",
  "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
  "tslint": "~6.1.0",
  "typescript": "~4.0.2"
 }
}
```

I think the problem is on the Dockerfile, but I don´t know if I´m missing an obvious thing or what could it be.

Thanks a lot in advance.

**EDIT**

As you can read on the comment below, I had problems trying to dockerize it by trying to run the container with *ng serve* and was asking myself why everybody was using the nginx server. So after I asked some friends their response was:

Ng serve is for develop, but when you try to dockerize your app, you should use the nginx server by coping the /dist files into the usr/nginx/share/html

I modified the docker so now it look like this:

```
FROM node:10-alpine as build-step

RUN mkdir -p /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json /app

RUN npm install

COPY . /app

RUN npm run build --prod

#NGINX

FROM nginx:1.17.1-alpine

COPY --from=build-step /app/dist/angular-tour-of-heroes /usr/share/nginx/html
```

By the way thanks to **FlorentB** for trying to help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read on the comment below, I had problems trying to dockerize it by trying to run the container with ng serve and was asking myself why everybody was using the nginx server. So after I asked some friends their response was:

Ng serve is for develop, but when you try to dockerize your app, you should use the nginx server by coping the /dist files into the usr/nginx/share/html

I modified the docker so now it look like this:

```
FROM node:10-alpine as build-step

RUN mkdir -p /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json /app

RUN npm install

COPY . /app

RUN npm run build --prod

#NGINX

FROM nginx:1.17.1-alpine

COPY --from=build-step /app/dist/angular-tour-of-heroes /usr/share/nginx/html
```

By the way thanks to FlorentB for trying to help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The entry point is not needed in the node dockerfile. It automatically starts using the npm start command

Nota :

- WORKDIR instructions selects the folder as the root of your following actions. No need to COPY in /src/app. Prefer .
- I would copy package*.json to also have the -lock file copied
- ng serve is performed because your package.json file sais so. **"start": "ng serve",
  ** line implies that when you use npm start it does ng serve.

Comment: Like:
FROM node:latest

RUN mkdir -p /src/app
WORKDIR /src/app

COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 4200
CMD [ "npm", "start"]

Because it´s not working for me like this.

I have seen most people use nginx, but I just want to run the angular app like I run it with ng serve